# How do I set an alias from a shell script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set an alias that applies to the current shell (the shell I'm running the script from) from a shell script. The alias is for `cd`-ing into the folder of the script. Here's the  (not working) script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases

DIR=$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd) # Detect the folder of the script.
alias cdr="cd $DIR" # cd into the folder.
```

I quickly realized that this didn't work because the alias it made was pertinent to the script's subshell.

Then, I tried to source the file (as in `. makeAlias.sh`). However, this produced an error: `dirname: illegal option -- b`.

How do I write a bash script that makes an alias relevant to the outer shell (the shell running the script)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the value of `$0` is now `-bash`. You might want to refactor your code to use a different reference point, or simply hard-code the path.

To answer the "how do I ...?" you aren't doing anything wrong, it's just that the logic has to be adapted to a different environment -- specifically, when you source a script, `$0` is that of the parent process, not the name of the script you are sourcing.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, maybe this alternative design could work?

```
newr () { r=$(pwd); }
cdr () { cd "$r"; }
newr
```

That is, `cdr` simply changes directory to whatever the variable `r` contains. The function `newr` can be used to conveniently set `r` to your current working directory. You'd define these in your `.bashrc` or similar, and use them interactively

Comment: I tried to find a good link for why to prefer functions over aliases, but couldn't find anything reasonably succinct and correct. Probably I'm too lazy. Anyway, aliases have some unfortunate and mildly surprising side effects e.g. when you try to supply parameters and the alias doesn't want them.

Answer (score 1):

`./makeAlias.sh` will be executed in a sub-shell and the changes made apply only the to sub-shell. Once the command terminates, the sub-shell goes and so do the changes.

Sourcing the file using `. ./makeAlias.sh` or `source ./makeAlias.sh` will read and execute commands from the file-name argument in the current shell context, that is when a script is run using `source` it runs within the existing shell, any variables created or modified by the script will remain available after the script completes.